# add custom form fields in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am building out invoice functionality for a Meteor app. The idea is to have line items that users can add and charge individually for each. 
I have a template for `lineItems`

```
<template name="lineItems">
  <div class="row line-item-0">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <h5 class="dmno-txt invoice-field border line-num">1</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-control-wrapper">
        <input class="dmno-green form-control empty" type="text" placeholder="What was this job" id="line-item-0" value={{lineItem0}} step="any">
        <span class="material-input"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="form-control-wrapper">
        <input class="form-control empty" type="number" placeholder="How much?" step="any" id="total" value={{total}}>
        <span class="material-input"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <div class="togglebutton">
        <label class="tax-toggle-label">
          <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="toggleTax"><span class="toggle"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am struggling to figure out a way to be able to add additional line items and dynamically change their corresponding id's.

Comment: wich id are you talking about?, mongo documents `_id`s ?

Comment: @Etjana When i'm going to be creating an `invoice` Object, i am going to populate each line item into an array `lineItems` so i want `invoice.lineItems` to return an array like `[ {"item": 0, "amount": 100, "taxable": true}, {"item": 1, "amount": 120, "taxable": true} ]` and in order to do that, each line item should have it's unique id in the front end, i assume.

Answer (score 0):

If your items are in an array and you need the id of the index when rendering you can use the gaelan:each-with-index package.. Then you can use it in your templates.

```
{{#eachWithIndex}}
    <div id="item-{{index}}"></div>
{{/eachWithIndex}}
```

Comment: rendering is one part of my problem, the other one is actually creating the array :/

Comment: This really looks like it would be a candidate for storing in a separate collection. This would allow you to insert, update and remove them easily.

Comment: i haven't set up the array yet because I have to set up the front end 'add/remove fields' first and i dont know how to set it up without using aldeed:autoform